# Angular - Universal with backend api PHP

Tags: angular, angular-universal

As I can see angular universal requirements are

- Angular 2 (obviously!)
- Node.js back end
- Webpack

So.. if my backend api is with PHP, can I use it? Node.js requirement is only for the rendering?

Comment: 'Universal' in A2 and 'universal' in A4 are totally different things. Any way, Node is needed only for rendering, but you're on your own with integrating it with PHP. You can call node script directly or you can set up Express server and proxy the requests to it, it's up to you.

Comment: So is there any good way to use Angular Universal if you are running PHP for backend API's?

Answer (score 2):

You can totally use PHP for your API backend. But the "backend" for your web application built with angular is something different than your API (in this context they call it "engine") - its just angular code interpreter that works on server side, so it can serve fully renderer HTML code (SEO ready).

Currently there are multiple "engines" you can use, but none of it is PHP. These are available: Express (node.js), ASP.NET Core and Hapi.

If you want to start with angular universal, I would suggest this seed project: https://github.com/angular/universal-starter